# How to read custom config from pytest.ini?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to provide custom parameters on the pytest.ini file and read it from code.

```
[pytest]
markers =
    regression: mark a test as regression.
    sanity: mark a test as sanity.
    critical: mark a test as critical.
addopts= -sv --html=report.html
custom_value= test
```

here i want to read **custom_value**
I have tried below but it's not working and throws **ValueError: no option named 'custom_value'**

```
def test_failtest(self, request):
    config = request.config
    tcv = config.getoption('custom_value')
    print "tcv->" + tcv
```

Comment: Reading the docs and checking hte source code I dont believe it supports custom values in it's config https://pytest.org/latest/customize.html

Comment: @lapinkoira so this is to say that the ini file only supports setting valid values for any of the `Builtin configuration file options` [(link)](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#builtin-configuration-file-options) leaving the developer no means to produce arbitrary options? I'm hoping to create an option to conditionally run extended tests vs basic tests and was looking for something built in instead of a homebrewed environment variable check or something of the like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use the `pytest_addoption` hook to make the option known:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini('custom_value', 'documentation of my custom value')
```

Comment: Also note that [`config.getoption()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.config.Config.getoption) should be replaced with [`config.getini()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.config.Config.getini).