# Pytest not picking up configurations inside pytest.ini

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to use values that I have in `pytest.ini` during testing but keep getting an error `FAILED tests/test_post_train.py::test_config - ValueError: unknown configuration value: 'rmse'`. I am using the method outline in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551090/how-to-read-custom-config-from-pytest-ini).

`pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
rmse = 40_000
inference_time = 0.5
```

`tests/test_post_train.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini("rmse", "Min RMSE score for a model to past post-train test")
    parser.addini(
        "inference_time", "Max inference time for the model to be making predictions"
    )


def test_config(request):
    score = request.config.getini("rmse")
    assert score == 40_000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=addoption#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) is a hook, so it should be in `conftest.py` and not in the test file

`conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini("rmse", "Min RMSE score for a model to past post-train test")
    parser.addini(
        "inference_time", "Max inference time for the model to be making predictions"
    )
```

`test_post_train.py`:

```
def test_config(request):
    score = request.config.getini("rmse")
    assert int(score) == 40_000
```

Comment: Hmm I am still getting an error, `ValueError: no option named 'rmse'`

Comment: @yudhiesh where are `conftest.py` and `pytest.ini` located? under the project root?

Comment: `conftest.py` is located in `tests` and `pytest.ini` is at the root dir.

Comment: @yudhiesh they both should be in the root. If you put a breakpoint in `pytest_addoption` you will see it's never executed in the current structure.